# Секундомер PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, таймер, сигналы-слоты

Как сделать так, чтобы при запуске приложения включался секундомер, 
который будет выводить часы, минуты и миллисекунды в `label`?

И как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии `pushButton` таймер останавливался 
и время в `label` оставалось?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(733, 532)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 389, 398, 86))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(222, 195, 299, 46))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(22)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ОСТАНОВИТЬ ТАЙМЕР"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "00:00:00:000"))

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 5):

Вам надо изучить класс `QTimer` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html.

Формат строки результата посмотрите и выберите себе самостоятельно https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#YearRange-enum.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(733, 532)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 389, 398, 86))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(222, 195, 299, 46))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(22)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ОСТАНОВИТЬ ТАЙМЕР"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "00:00:00:000"))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.setText("ЗАПУСТИТЬ ТАЙМЕР")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.click_button)
        
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.displayTime)

    def click_button(self):
        if self.pushButton.text() == "ЗАПУСТИТЬ ТАЙМЕР":
            self.timer.start()
            self.pushButton.setText("ОСТАНОВИТЬ ТАЙМЕР")
        else:     
            self.timer.stop()
            self.pushButton.setText("ЗАПУСТИТЬ ТАЙМЕР")
            
    def displayTime(self):
        self.label.setText(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString())
        self.label.adjustSize()
        

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> я имел ввиду после нажатия кнопки должен начинаться отчет миллисекунд и секунд как обычный секундомер

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(733, 532)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 389, 398, 86))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(222, 195, 299, 46))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(22)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ОСТАНОВИТЬ ТАЙМЕР"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "00:00:00:000"))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.setText("ЗАПУСТИТЬ ТАЙМЕР")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.click_button)
        
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(100)                                                    # +
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.displayTime)

    def click_button(self):
        if self.pushButton.text() == "ЗАПУСТИТЬ ТАЙМЕР":
            self.timer.start()
            self.pushButton.setText("ОСТАНОВИТЬ ТАЙМЕР")
        else:     
            self.timer.stop()
            self.pushButton.setText("ЗАПУСТИТЬ ТАЙМЕР")
            
    def displayTime(self):
#        self.label.setText(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString())
        self.label.setText(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString('hh:mm:ss:zzz'))  # +++
        self.label.adjustSize()
        

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update 2**

> извиняюсь, но мне надо надо сделать так чтоб label показывал секунды с нуля а не с текущего время на пк. Я не понимаю как это сделать

Я вам предложу все, что вам может пригодиться.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QRadioButton, \
    QSpinBox, QWidget, QLCDNumber, QLabel, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal,pyqtSlot,QTimer
import time


class Timer(QDialog):
    timeout = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.time = 0
        self.timeInterval = 1000                              # По умолчанию секунды

        self.timerUp = QTimer()
        self.timerUp.setInterval(self.timeInterval)
        self.timerUp.timeout.connect(self.updateUptime)

        self.timerDown = QTimer()
        self.timerDown.setInterval(self.timeInterval)
        self.timerDown.timeout.connect(self.updateDowntime)

        self.initUi()

        self.buttonStart.clicked.connect(self.timerUp.start)
        self.buttonStop.clicked.connect(self.timerUp.stop)
        self.buttonReset.clicked.connect(self.reset)
        self.buttonCountDown.clicked.connect(self.timerDown.start)
        self.buttonStopAlarm.clicked.connect(self.timerDown.stop)
        self.timeSpinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.settimer)

    def initUi(self):
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.groupBox = QGroupBox(" Выбираем интервал ")
        self.radioButton1 = QRadioButton("s")
        self.radioButton1.toggled.connect(self.setUnit)
        self.radioButton2 = QRadioButton("0.1s")
        self.radioButton2.toggled.connect(self.setUnit)
        self.radioButton3 = QRadioButton("0.01s")
        self.radioButton3.toggled.connect(self.setUnit)
        self.radioButton4 = QRadioButton("1ms")
        self.radioButton4.toggled.connect(self.setUnit)
        self.radioButton1.setChecked(True)
        self.unitLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.unitLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton1)
        self.unitLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton2)
        self.unitLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton3)
        self.unitLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton4)
        self.groupBox.setLayout(self.unitLayout)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox)

        self.buttonStart = QPushButton(self.tr("start"))
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.buttonStart)

        self.buttonStop = QPushButton(self.tr("stop"))
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.buttonStop)

        self.timeViewer = QLCDNumber()
        self.timeViewer.setFixedHeight(45)     
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.timeViewer)

        self.timeForHuman = QLabel()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.timeForHuman)

        self.buttonReset = QPushButton(self.tr("reset"))
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.buttonReset)

        self.timeSpinBox = QSpinBox()
        self.timeSpinBox.setRange(0, 1000000000)                
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.timeSpinBox)
        
        self.groupBoxCountDown = QGroupBox(" Обратный отсчет ")
        countDown = QVBoxLayout()
        self.buttonCountDown = QPushButton(self.tr("Cтарт"))
        self.buttonStopAlarm = QPushButton(self.tr("Стоп"))
        
        countDown.addWidget(self.buttonCountDown)
        countDown.addWidget(self.buttonStopAlarm)
        self.groupBoxCountDown.setLayout(countDown)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.groupBoxCountDown)

    def setUnit(self):
        if self.radioButton1.isChecked():
            self.timeInterval = 1000
        elif self.radioButton2.isChecked():
            self.timeInterval = 100
        elif self.radioButton3.isChecked():
            self.timeInterval = 10
        elif self.radioButton1.isChecked():
            self.timeInterval = 1
        self.timerUp.setInterval(self.timeInterval)
        self.timerDown.setInterval(self.timeInterval)

    def updateUptime(self):
        self.time += 1
        self.settimer(self.time)

    def updateDowntime(self):
        self.time =self.time-1
        self.settimer(self.time)
        if self.time <=0:
            self.timeout.emit()

    def settimer(self,int):
        self.time=int
        self.timeViewer.display(self.time)
        if self.timeInterval ==1000:
            self.timeForHuman.setText(
                time.strftime('%H hour %M minute %S second', time.gmtime(self.time)))
        elif self.timeInterval ==100:
            self.timeForHuman.setText(
                time.strftime('%H hour %M minute %S second', time.gmtime(self.time/10)))
        elif self.timeInterval ==10:
            self.timeForHuman.setText(
                time.strftime('%H hour %M minute %S second', time.gmtime(self.time/100)))
        elif self.timeInterval ==1:
            self.timeForHuman.setText(
                time.strftime('%H hour %M minute %S second', time.gmtime(self.time/1000)))

    def reset(self):
        self.time=0
        self.settimer(self.time)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    timer = Timer()
    def beep():
        print('\a')
    timer.timeout.connect(beep)
    timer.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я имел ввиду после нажатия кнопки должен начинаться отчет миллисекунд и секунд как обычный секундомер

Comment: @ДимаНейзвестный я добавил некоторые изменения.

Comment: извиняюсь, но мне надо надо сделать так чтоб label показывал секунды с нуля а не с текущего время на пк. Я не понимаю как это сделать

Comment: @ДимаНейзвестный смотрите обновление, теперь вы вооружены и очень опасны :)

Comment: @S.Nick надо ещё время круга добавить ;)

Comment: @eri как только вопрос зададут, так сразу и добавлю :)